# DataTable : Using a function with ajax.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have some troubles with the method `ajax.reload()` - nothing happens. I've tested with this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "async": false,
            "url": "arrays.txt",
            "dataSrc": function(json){return json;} // really necessary ?
        }
    } );

    $('#reload').click(function () {
        table.ajax.reload(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }, false);
    } );
} );
```

arrays.txt contents :

```
[
        [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ]
]
```

and html contents :

```
<button id="reload">reload</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

If I change "your" code (dataTables.js) to

```
if(callback){
  var api = new _Api( settings );
  callback( api.ajax.json() );
}
```

instead of

```
if(callback){
  var api = new _Api( settings );
  api.one( 'draw', function(){
    callback( api.ajax.json() );
  });
}
```

it works for me...

Actually, it works if you click a second time on the button, but this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

I have removed `async: false`, it seems unnecessary, however the code works with this option as well.

Option `dataSrc` is needed because you're returning array of arrays as your data, but it could be simplified as `dataSrc: ""`. From the [manual](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc):

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty string.

See the example below for demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   // AJAX emulation for demonstration only
   $.mockjax({
      url: 'arrays.txt',
      responseTime: 200,
      response: function(settings){
        this.responseText = [
        [
           "Tiger Nixon",
           "System Architect",
           "Edinburgh",
           "5421",
           new Date(),
           "$320,800"
        ],
        [
          "Garrett Winters",
          "Accountant",
          "Tokyo",
          "8422",
          new Date(),
          "$170,750"
        ]
      ]
     }
   });

   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       "ajax": {
           url: "arrays.txt",
           dataSrc: ""
       }
   });
  
   $('#reload').click(function () {
       table.ajax.reload(function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }, false);
   } );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
<button id="reload">reload</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```